# track user input from UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-input, uikeyboard

How can I get user input of the UIKeyboard on the iPhone?
I want to track, if the user hits "backspace" when the firstResponder UITextField is empty.
I know how I can track a text change but if the field is empty the text don't change when hit "backspace".

Answer (score 1):

You can put a single space character as the default textfield text.  If it tries to disappear in your textshouldchange delegate then the user hit a backspace.  You can remove the leading space before actually using the text result.

Comment: Would be a solution, but don't work for me because I already implement the textChange Notification and the delegates shouldBeginEditing, shouldEndEditing, didEndEditing and didBeginEditing. The firstResponder changes on every user interaction depending on his input.
I need a other solution. Is it not possible to get directly the users input on the UIKeyboad?